# Keep a live boot installer up to date

Tags: boot, usb

Suppose I have a bootable USB thumbstick. Every time I install the image on a system, it's in an environment with poor internet connection/speed. So I'd like to know if there's a simple way to keep the image on the stick up to date with all the packages I want, so that installing the system would require minimal updates?

I tried running `apt upgrade` in a normal 32GB USB thumbstick, but it would become unresponsive quickly. Would doing that on an external M.2 enclosure instead work, and would that even achieve what I want?

Comment: The live installer does not change. But 22.04.1 is an update over 22.04 and 22.04.2 will be out by the End of Feb, 2023 with all current updates. I find installing from a M.2 SSD using USB3 adapter is so much faster than flash drives, I may not buy any more flash drives. And expect eventually to use USB-C which should then be even faster. I already have many, so really do not need them.

Comment: @oldfred that would mean no updates between ISO releases

Comment: I'm involved with QA; and just set off my `zsync_jammy` script when I want to upgrade to the latest daily. It updates the *daily* and then provides me with a `diff` of the manifest (current vs. my last) so I can peruse changes if wanted, with it then highlighting specific package changes that interest me ... but loads of scripts that `zsync` are available. I ran my `check_jammy` version & it tells me the 5.19 kernel still isn't there today :( but a casper change requires my attention... NOTE:  *daily* ISOs can include ***-proposed*** packages (`casper` I mention being an example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no official updated iso files between the released versions.

But there are **daily** built iso files of all versions being developed, the 'next one' now 23.04 to be released in April (a short-life version) and the currently newest LTS release, now 'jammy' alias 22.04.x LTS. Those iso files are published at the [ISO testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/) for testing purposes, and you are welcome to use them.

I would recommend 'jammy'. If you use it to install, you may want to turn off the 'proposed' repo in the installed system in order to avoid getting versions of programs, that are not yet tested and accepted.

---

As indicated by oldfred, It is a good idea to use an SSD connected via USB instead of a pendrive. It is faster and much more reliable, responsive enough and big enough for heavy updates & upgrades. So you can keep a [persistent live](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) system up to date with

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

without problems (I have tested it with many repeated updates & upgrades).

But it is better, easier and more reliable to get a fresh iso file from the ISO testing tracker instead of keeping a persistent live system up to date. Also, if I remember correctly, persistent live upgrades will not affect the installation, so if you want to install up to date program packages, you should get a current daily iso file.

If you use `zsync` you need to download only the modified parts of the iso file since your previous download and there is an automatic checksum test. Details to install and use zsync:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zsync

zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
```

I suggest that you run `zsync` at home or some other place where you have a fast internet connection. Then you can use the up to date live system where there is a slow internet connection.

---

Finally, you are welcome to (but need not) participate in the ISO testing and report bugs ;-)

Comment: So changes to the persistent partition don't affect the installations, as I thought. Is there a way to use the data on that partition to get the updated packages without having to redownload them. Or would I have to pre-download all updates (`apt download`) manually every time?

Comment: I suggest the solution to `zsync` the [jammy] iso file from the iso testing tracker, and that way get a fully up to date live (live-only) system, that will install up to date program packages when creating an installed system. I think this is a straightforward way. -- How many systems do you intend to install and how often? How similar are they? Would it be an option to use the [OEM installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview) method: create a master and clone it?

Comment: Can you give me a link to some materials of your recommendation so I can look into the `zsync` method? I may not install them often (once in 3 months maybe), but I might have to do it on site with a couple Mbps download, so getting all the updates and necessary packages is.. not fun. I don't think the OEM installation will work, I need the system to be in ready to use state.

Comment: Assuming you want standard Ubuntu Desktop, I updated the answer with commands to install and use `zsync`.